# How can i build a real relocatable SDK with Pre-Built/Installed Crosstool-NG toolchain via buildroot in a docker container?

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot, toolchain, crosstool-ng

**Setup:**

- Host : Ubuntu 20.04 **Docker** container
- WorkspacePath : `/workspace`
- External ToolChain : **Pre-Built and installed** at `/workspace/crosstool_ng/arm-**`
- BuildSystem : BuildRoot at `/workspace/buildroot`
- BuildrootOutput : `/workspace/buildroot/images/*`

With above setup am trying to build BSP(`make`) and SDK(`make sdk`) in my docker container. Everything goes well,

but make sdk generates a tarball conaining sysroot and toolchain and that toolchain is **still pointing symbolic link to fix/absolute path** that docker conainer starting from `/workspace/**`.

If I take that tarball and move to host or any other PC then it will not work. We have that `relocate_sdk.sh` script but that's not helping me also.

**Workaround:**
If I buld my SDK directly on host then this fix path will be still there so it works but that i dont want.I want a relocatable sdk that i can give to anyone.

Can someone help me with this issue (specially it needs to be built under docker)